# Rails Gritter Ajax setup

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, gritter

**OR Maybe someone knows a better flash notification system for ajax???** (edit)

I'm struggling to get the grittier( https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter ) notification working with ajax, this is what I got so far:

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= gflash %>
<%= gflash :js => true %>
```

**request_fr.rb**

```
  def request_fr
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
        gflash :now, :notice => "TEST gflash :now, :notice =>"
        gflash :success => "TEST2 gflash :success => "
      end
  end
```

**request_fr.js.erb** (tried many things here, nothing seems to work)

```
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice].to_s, :image => :notice, :title => "Pay attention!", :sticky => true) %>
<%= gflash :js => true %>
 <% if flash.now[:notice] %>
    $.gritter.add({
      title: '--',
      text: '<%= escape_javascript(flash.now[:notice].to_s) %>'
    });
  <% end %>
```

**one of the errors** DONT GET THIS ANYMORE, .to_s fixed it. but still don't get the message

```
Rendered friendships/request_fr.js.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 97ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for ["TEST gflash :now, :notice =>"]:Array:
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:30:in `escape_javascript'
  gritter (1.1.0) lib/gritter/helpers.rb:19:in `add_gritter'
  app/views/friendships/request_fr.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_friendships_request_fr_js_erb__426745901290841
9434_2281294440'
```

Not quite sure how to set it up, tried a lot of different ways ;/

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:
In your js file put

```
     <%= add_gritter("Notice", :image => :success, :title => "Notice" ) %>
```